# Regular expression to match non-zero prefixed numeric *OR* alphanumeric

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds, semantic-versioning

I have written a regular expression that matches against a string that is compliant with the [Semantic Versioning 2.0.0](http://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html) specification (see below).

The middle section of the expression deals with parsing the pre-release version. This section is prefixed with a hyphen (-) and can have one or more identifiers that are separated by periods (.). Each identifier is alphanumeric (0-9, A-Z, a-z or a hyphen) but **if the identifier is numeric then it must *NOT* start with a leading zero**.

Is there a more concise way to represent the alternation group that I'm using to enforce the non-zero-prefix rule?

This regex is for .NET, written using the 'x' mode in order to allow comments and ignore white space.

```
^

# ====================================
# Main Major.Minor.Path version number
# ====================================
(?<version>
    (?<major>[1-9]\d*|0)
    \.
    (?<minor>[1-9]\d*|0)
    \.
    (?<patch>[1-9]\d*|0)
)

# ===========================
# Optional preprelease string
# ===========================
(?:
    -                                   # Hyphen indicates start of prerelease.
    (?<prerelease>
        #======================================================================
        # CONFUSION STARTS HERE
        (?:
            [1-9]\d*                    # Numeric identifier (no leading zero).
            |
            [A-Za-z-]+                  # Alpha identifier.
            |
            \d+[A-Za-z-]+[0-9A-Za-z-]*  # Alphanumeric starting w/ numeric.
            |
            [A-Za-z-]+\d+[0-9A-Za-z-]*  # Alphanumeric starting w/ alpha.
        )
        # CONFUSION ENDS HERE - ish
        #======================================================================
        (?:
            \.                          # start of another identifier.
            (
                [1-9]\d*
                |
                [A-Za-z-]+
                |
                \d+[A-Za-z-]+[0-9A-Za-z-]*
                |
                [A-Za-z-]+\d+[0-9A-Za-z-]*
            )
        )*
    )
)?

# =====================
# Optional build string
# =====================
(?:
    \+                                  # Plus sign indicates start of build string.
    (?<build>
        [0-9A-Za-z-]+
        (?:
            \.                          # start of another identifier.
            [0-9A-Za-z-]+
        )*
    )
)?

$
```

I think the solution might have something to do with lookaround operators, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Looks OK, whats the problem?

Comment: No problem per se, @sln. It's quite a long regex though, and I wondered if it would possible to reduce the complexity of that middle section and make its intention more obvious. I'm thinking about those that follow me, really. Aren't I kind? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Might be able to shorten up Prerelease a bit
**edit**
Added a possible fix for the [1-9] being possibly plagued by backtracking.
Uses a lookahead.

```
 (?:
       -
       (?<prerelease>
            (?:
                 [1-9] \d* (?![\w-])
              |  \d+ [A-Za-z-]+ [0-9A-Za-z-]* 
              |  [A-Za-z-]+ (?: \d+ [0-9A-Za-z-]* )?
            )
            (?:
                 \.
                 (?:
                      [1-9] \d* (?![\w-]) 
                   |  \d+ [A-Za-z-]+ [0-9A-Za-z-]* 
                   |  [A-Za-z-]+ (?: \d+ [0-9A-Za-z-]* )?
                 )
            )*
       )
  )?
```

Comment: Ahhh, neat solution to the backtracking problem.